# Remote Desktop Licensing firewall requirements

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2016, remote-desktop-services

We have a very strictly segmented network within our Active Directory domain. Server1 in Segment1 has a Remote Desktop Licensing role installed, whereas Server2 in Segment2 will have Remote Desktop Session Host role installed.

There are no other requirement considerations (i.e. internet accessibility or CRLs) and Server1 has full Domain member connectivity already. I'm not very familiar with all the features of RDS and its possibilities and I'm having a hard time finding the absolute minimum network port requirements for Server2 to retrieve its licenses from Server1 in this particular scenario.

Is it even possible to have more minimal firewall configuration besides all the default domain member ports?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/832017/service-overview-and-network-port-requirements-for-windows

Comment: I assume that Terminal Services Licensing would be the correct bit, but it's also referenceing to a "File and Printer Sharing" feature - which is not described in the article.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you have these two server segregated?

Comment: I install the licensing service on each RDS server.

Comment: @joeqwerty It's based on the administrative tier model; https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/securing-privileged-access/securing-privileged-access-reference-material